# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{n+2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

In an exercise I'm asked to evaluate the following limit:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{n + 2^n}$$

I arrived at the conclusion that:

$$\frac{n!}{n + 2^n} \geq \frac{n!}{2^n}$$

So my plan is to prove that $\frac{n!}{2^n}$ diverges and as a consequence show that $\frac{n!}{n + 2^n}$ also diverges, But I'm not being able to do so.

How can I prove that $\lim n! / 2^n$ is infinity?

Comment: Surely a duplicate somewhere on this site, if you looked a little harder. But more pedagogically: how would you explain $n!$ and $2^n$ to your bright 12-year-old cousin? What does this imply about their behavior?

Comment: Also your inequality points the wrong way: bigger denominators mean smaller terms.

Comment: $n!>1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4^{n-3}=6\cdot 2^{2n-6}$. Therefore, $n!/2^n>2^{n-6}\cdot 6=\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: This question is partially or fully (depending on how you want to view it) answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r).

Comment: Use the inequality $n!>(n/2)^{n/2}$ .

Comment: As pointed out already your inequality is wrong. Miguel's answer let's you know how to prove $\frac{n!}{2^n}$ diverges. Then you can use the limit comparison test to show that $\frac{n!}{n+2^n}$ also diverges.

Comment: Specifically with $2^n$ rather than $x^n$: [Show that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{2^{n}} = \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1145150) or [How can I calculate the limit of exponential divided by factorial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/241218)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that for $n \ge 2$, we have $\frac{n!}{2^n} = \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n-1}{2} \cdot \dots \frac {2}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \ge \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{n}{4}$, which diverges to $\infty$.

I'll point out that your inequality is wrong, since $n +2^n \ge 2^n$, though. You could fix this by establishing something like $n + 2^n \le 2^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*:

$$\forall n>3, \frac{n!}{n+2^n} \geqslant \frac{n(n-1)2^{n-3}}{n+2^n} = \frac{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-3}}+\frac 8n} > \frac{n-1}{1+8}.$$